# Highchart (Column Chart) : Few data labels are not appearing for a series

Tags: highcharts

I am creating a column chart using High Charts -- I am not able to show all the data labels for all the series in the chart. I have two series in a column chart while the first series shows all the data labels the second series do not displays few of the data labels while displaying others.

Prompt help will highly be appreciated.

Please refer the [Fiddle Sample](http://jsfiddle.net/bhupendrasinghnegi/cthzmsg0/) to have hands on.

```
"chart": {
        "type": "column",
        "plotShadow": false,
        "polar": false,
        "renderTo": ""
    },
    "credits": {
        "enabled": false
    },
    "title": {
        "text": ""
    },
    "xAxis": {
        "categories": ["Category 1", "Category 2", "Category 3", "Category 4", "Category 5", "Category 6", "Category 7", "Category 8", "Category 9"],
        "labels": {
            "enabled": true,
            "style": {
                "fontSize": "8px",
                "fontFamily": "Arial"
            }
        },
        "lineWidth": 1,
        "tickWidth": 0,
        "title": {
            "text": "",
            "style": {
                "fontFamily": "Arial"
            }
        }
    },
    "yAxis": {
        "lineWidth": 1,
        "title": {
            "text": "",
            "style": {
                "fontFamily": "Arial"
            }
        },
        "gridLineWidth": 0,
        "labels": {
            "enabled": true,
            "format": "{value:.0f}",
            "style": {
                "fontSize": "8px",
                "fontFamily": "Arial"
            }
        },
        "startOnTick": true,
        "endOnTick": true
    },
    "series": [{
        "name": "Company Value",
        "data": [{
            "name": "Adidas Group",
            "color": "#f1b11d",
            "y": 63.0,
            "showInLegend": false,
            "dataLabels": {
                "align": "center",
                "enabled": true,
                "borderColor": "",
                "rotation": 0,
                "style": {
                    "fontSize": "8px",
                    "fontFamily": "Arial"
                }
            },
            "borderColor": "#ffffff",
            "enableMouseTracking": false,
            "sliced": false,
            "selected": false
        }, {
            "name": "Adidas Group",
            "color": "#f1b11d",
            "y": 24.0,
            "showInLegend": false,
            "dataLabels": {
                "align": "center",
                "enabled": true,
                "borderColor": "",
                "rotation": 0,
                "style": {
                    "fontSize": "8px",
                    "fontFamily": "Arial"
                }
            },
            "borderColor": "#ffffff",
            "enableMouseTracking": false,
            "sliced": false,
            "selected": false
        }, {
            "name": "Adidas Group",
            "color": "#f1b11d",
            "y": 177.0,
            "showInLegend": false,
            "dataLabels": {
                "align": "center",
                "enabled": true,
                "borderColor": "",
                "rotation": 0,
                "style": {
                    "fontSize": "8px",
                    "fontFamily": "Arial"
                }
            },
            "borderColor": "#ffffff",
            "enableMouseTracking": false,
            "sliced": false,
            "selected": false
        }, {
            "name": "Adidas Group",
            "color": "#f1b11d",
            "y": 197.0,
            "showInLegend": false,
            "dataLabels": {
                "align": "center",
                "enabled": true,
                "borderColor": "",
                "rotation": 0,
                "style": {
                    "fontSize": "8px",
                    "fontFamily": "Arial"
                }
            },
            "borderColor": "#ffffff",
            "enableMouseTracking": false,
            "sliced": false,
            "selected": false
        }, {
            "name": "Adidas Group",
            "color": "#f1b11d",
            "y": 224.0,
            "showInLegend": false,
            "dataLabels": {
                "align": "center",
                "enabled": true,
                "borderColor": "",
                "rotation": 0,
                "style": {
                    "fontSize": "8px",
                    "fontFamily": "Arial"
                }
            },
            "borderColor": "#ffffff",
            "enableMouseTracking": false,
            "sliced": false,
            "selected": false
        }, {
            "name": "Adidas Group",
            "color": "#f1b11d",
            "y": 297.0,
            "showInLegend": false,
            "dataLabels": {
                "align": "center",
                "enabled": true,
                "borderColor": "",
                "rotation": 0,
                "style": {
                    "fontSize": "8px",
                    "fontFamily": "Arial"
                }
            },
            "borderColor": "#ffffff",
            "enableMouseTracking": false,
            "sliced": false,
            "selected": false
        }, {
            "name": "Adidas Group",
            "color": "#f1b11d",
            "y": 349.0,
            "showInLegend": false,
            "dataLabels": {
                "align": "center",
                "enabled": true,
                "borderColor": "",
                "rotation": 0,
                "style": {
                    "fontSize": "8px",
                    "fontFamily": "Arial"
                }
            },
            "borderColor": "#ffffff",
            "enableMouseTracking": false,
            "sliced": false,
            "selected": false
        }, {
            "name": "Adidas Group",
            "color": "#f1b11d",
            "y": 903.0,
            "showInLegend": false,
            "dataLabels": {
                "align": "center",
                "enabled": true,
                "borderColor": "",
                "rotation": 0,
                "style": {
                    "fontSize": "8px",
                    "fontFamily": "Arial"
                }
            },
            "borderColor": "#ffffff",
            "enableMouseTracking": false,
            "sliced": false,
            "selected": false
        }, {
            "name": "Adidas Group",
            "color": "#f1b11d",
            "y": 20.0,
            "showInLegend": false,
            "dataLabels": {
                "align": "center",
                "enabled": true,
                "borderColor": "",
                "rotation": 0,
                "style": {
                    "fontSize": "8px",
                    "fontFamily": "Arial"
                }
            },
            "borderColor": "#ffffff",
            "enableMouseTracking": false,
            "sliced": false,
            "selected": false
        }],
        "regression": false,
        "enableMouseTracking": true,
        "color": "#f1b11d",
        "showInLegend": false
    }, {
        "name": "All Companies Average Score",
        "data": [{
            "name": "All Companies",
            "color": "#00aeef",
            "y": 25.0,
            "showInLegend": false,
            "dataLabels": {
                "align": "center",
                "enabled": true,
                "borderColor": "",
                "rotation": 0,
                "style": {
                    "fontSize": "8px",
                    "fontFamily": "Arial"
                }
            },
            "borderColor": "#ffffff",
            "enableMouseTracking": false,
            "sliced": false,
            "selected": false
        }, {
            "name": "All Companies",
            "color": "#00aeef",
            "y": 18.0,
            "showInLegend": false,
            "dataLabels": {
                "align": "center",
                "enabled": true,
                "borderColor": "",
                "rotation": 0,
                "style": {
                    "fontSize": "8px",
                    "fontFamily": "Arial"
                }
            },
            "borderColor": "#ffffff",
            "enableMouseTracking": false,
            "sliced": false,
            "selected": false
        }, {
            "name": "All Companies",
            "color": "#00aeef",
            "y": 90.0,
            "showInLegend": false,
            "dataLabels": {
                "align": "center",
                "enabled": true,
                "borderColor": "",
                "rotation": 0,
                "style": {
                    "fontSize": "8px",
                    "fontFamily": "Arial"
                }
            },
            "borderColor": "#ffffff",
            "enableMouseTracking": false,
            "sliced": false,
            "selected": false
        }, {
            "name": "All Companies",
            "color": "#00aeef",
            "y": 1821.0,
            "showInLegend": false,
            "dataLabels": {
                "align": "center",
                "enabled": true,
                "borderColor": "",
                "rotation": 0,
                "style": {
                    "fontSize": "8px",
                    "fontFamily": "Arial"
                }
            },
            "borderColor": "#ffffff",
            "enableMouseTracking": false,
            "sliced": false,
            "selected": false
        }, {
            "name": "All Companies",
            "color": "#00aeef",
            "y": 84.0,
            "showInLegend": false,
            "dataLabels": {
                "align": "center",
                "enabled": true,
                "borderColor": "",
                "rotation": 0,
                "style": {
                    "fontSize": "8px",
                    "fontFamily": "Arial"
                }
            },
            "borderColor": "#ffffff",
            "enableMouseTracking": false,
            "sliced": false,
            "selected": false
        }, {
            "name": "All Companies",
            "color": "#00aeef",
            "y": 83.0,
            "showInLegend": false,
            "dataLabels": {
                "align": "center",
                "enabled": true,
                "borderColor": "",
                "rotation": 0,
                "style": {
                    "fontSize": "8px",
                    "fontFamily": "Arial"
                }
            },
            "borderColor": "#ffffff",
            "enableMouseTracking": false,
            "sliced": false,
            "selected": false
        }, {
            "name": "All Companies",
            "color": "#00aeef",
            "y": 97.0,
            "showInLegend": false,
            "dataLabels": {
                "align": "center",
                "enabled": true,
                "borderColor": "",
                "rotation": 0,
                "style": {
                    "fontSize": "8px",
                    "fontFamily": "Arial"
                }
            },
            "borderColor": "#ffffff",
            "enableMouseTracking": false,
            "sliced": false,
            "selected": false
        }, {
            "name": "All Companies",
            "color": "#00aeef",
            "y": 241.0,
            "showInLegend": false,
            "dataLabels": {
                "align": "center",
                "enabled": true,
                "borderColor": "",
                "rotation": 0,
                "style": {
                    "fontSize": "8px",
                    "fontFamily": "Arial"
                }
            },
            "borderColor": "#ffffff",
            "enableMouseTracking": false,
            "sliced": false,
            "selected": false
        }, {
            "name": "All Companies",
            "color": "#00aeef",
            "y": 12.0,
            "showInLegend": false,
            "dataLabels": {
                "align": "center",
                "enabled": true,
                "borderColor": "",
                "rotation": 0,
                "style": {
                    "fontSize": "8px",
                    "fontFamily": "Arial"
                }
            },
            "borderColor": "#ffffff",
            "enableMouseTracking": false,
            "sliced": false,
            "selected": false
        }],
        "regression": false,
        "enableMouseTracking": true,
        "color": "#00aeef",
        "showInLegend": false
    }],
    "plotOptions": {
        "series": {
            "enableMouseTracking": false,
            "dataLabels": {
                "color": "#000000",
                "enabled": true,
                "borderColor": "",
                "format": "{y:.0f}"
            }
        },
        "column": {
            "pointWidth": 20
        }
    },
    "exporting": {
        "enabled": false
    },
    "tooltip": {
        "enabled": true,
        "pointFormat": "{series.name}: {point.y:.0f}",
        "shared": false,
        "headerFormat": ""
    },
    "legend": {
        "enabled": false,
        "x": 0,
        "floating": false,
        "shadow": false,
        "reversed": false,
        "y": 0
    }
```

Comment: Set [allowOverlap](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.dataLabels.allowOverlap) to true: http://jsfiddle.net/cthzmsg0/1/

Comment: @PawelFus : Thanks a lot for this info. This has helped me a lot. Please do add that as ur answer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Set [plotOptions.series.dataLabels.allowOverlap](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.series.dataLabels.allowOverlap) option to `true`. See : http://jsfiddle.net/cthzmsg0/1

Comment: Thanks a lot! That has been bugging me for months :)

Comment: how to add X axis series name `function BarSeriesData(val, name) {barChart.series[0].name = name;barChart.series[0].setData(val);}`   In this code name value is not reflected in graph, but setData is working.

Comment: Use [series.update()](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/Series.update).