# Highcharts automatically drop the xAxis labels

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I've upgraded to highchart 5.0.7 from highcharts 4 a week ago. All the charts that were working properly have started to drop the labels on xAxis.

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lakshya_8/44jh7wp7/), If I resize the chart sometimes I see the only First and Last as the labels on the xAxis. What I want is all the labels should be visible no matter what the size of the chart.

I have also tried the `series.labels{ step:1 }` option but it did not work.

Can anyone please help me with this ?

Comment: have you tried allowOverlap option ? you can find example here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28681251/highchart-column-chart-few-data-labels-are-not-appearing-for-a-series

Comment: Thanks  @TechnoCrat  ! But overlapping will drop the labels and I want all the labels to be drawn, so I think allowOverLap is no useful in my case.

Comment: You should set xAxis.labels.step = 1, not series.labels http://jsfiddle.net/44jh7wp7/1/